# Mixing GlobalID::Identification for form object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, garbage-collection

Rails 4.2.5

I have Form object `Feedback`.

```
class Feedback
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :name, :message

  validates :name, :message, presence: true
end
```

And controller `FeedbacksController`

```
  def create
    @feedback = Feedback.new(feedback_params)
    if @feedback.valid?
      FeedbackServiceMailer.new_feedback(@feedback).deliver_later
      redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Thanks for your feedback!'
    else
      render :index, status: 400
    end
  end
```

To be able to pass `@feedback` object to Mailer. I have added `GlobalID::Identification` mixin and provided `id` and `self.find` methods:

```
  def id
    object_id
  end

  def self.find(id)
    ObjectSpace._id2ref(id.to_i)
  end
```

My question, is it okay to provide `object_id` for deserializing Form object?

As I understood Ruby GC will not collect `@feedback` object if something have a reference to it.